# Regex for modifying html 'img' tag

Tags: regex

I have a requirement where I need to modify html 'img' tags in an html string that do not end with a `'/>'`
ex: `<img src="">` needs to be changed to `<img src=""/>`
I am using following regex: `<img(.*[^/])>` to replace with `<img$1/>`

This works fine however for cases like: `<center><img src=""/></center>` the regex returns: `<center><img src=""></center/>`

Any suggestions how to impact this regex only upto the end of the img tag? Thanks.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: Try using `<img(.*?[^/])>`. This makes the regex non-greedy

Comment: @Biffen its actually a html string that I am applying regex on. The servlet response is the content string that has these img tags which I need to modify.

Comment: @ShubhankitRoy What do you think HTML is if not a string?! How is that any different? You still can't parse HTML with regex.

Comment: @Psi Already tried. Didn't work. Updated the description, please check.

Comment: @ShubhankitRoy have you checked my answer ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman Nope, I guess I'll have to use a html parser. Thanks though.

Comment: What language are you using? RegEx is actually the wrong tool for this

Comment: @MacroMan I am using Java. However, I did a workaround for this requirement. As I just needed to alter the mentioned small portion of html, I got all my matching image tags using `<img(.*?)>` and then applied some logic on the captured group to properly modify the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
<\s*img\s+([^>]*=(?:\".*?\"|\'.*?\'))[\s\w\-]*>
```

with following replace by:

```
<img $1/>
```

this will match these simple and complex cases:

```
<img src="images/a.jpg" title="test"><br/>
<img  src="a/b.jpg" >
<span><img src="a.jpg"></span>
<img src="" title="">
<img src="" data-val>
<img src="a.jpg" title="a'>b">
<img src="a.jpg" title='a">b'>
<img src="a.jpg" title='a>=b"=>' >
```

but not following:

```
<img src="a.jpg" />
<imgXTag src="b.jpg" >
<img src="a.jpg" /  >
```

[Sample Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5RBq7/3)